# Timer with fixed delays between Task

Tags: java, timer

I want to have a timer task that runs two tasks with fixed delays between each task.

For example:

A------B-----A------B
0------10----20----30

I tried using this code:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(taskA, 0, 10000);
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(taskB, 10000, 10000);
```

but that gives me:

A-----A,B-----A,B
0-----10------20

How do I do this using Timer and TimerTask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just double your interval:

```
  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(taskA, 0, 20000);
  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(taskB, 10000, 20000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create one Timer and have it alternate the the task it calls.  Or create two Timers that one for Task A and one for Task B that have double the delay.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with a single Task that maintains an internal toggle.